# Merge Procedure, Insert By Order CREATED_DATETIME

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, merge, sql-order-by

In MERGE PROCEDURE, how can we use order by while inserting? I want to insert those records which are ORDER BY CREATED_DATETIME from the SRC table.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE FULFILLABLE_ORDERS 
AS 
BEGIN 
   MERGE INTO RPT_SCI.ORDER_FULFILLABLE TRGT 
   USING (
      select * 
      from RPT_SCI.VI_ORDER_FULFILLABLE 
      order by CREATED_DTTM DESC
   ) SRC ON ( TRGT.TC_ORDER_ID = SRC.TC_ORDER_ID) 
   WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE (.............) 
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (..............);
END;
```

My database is Oracle.

Comment: Please show what you have tried first.

Comment: create or replace PROCEDURE  FULFILLABLE_ORDERS AS
BEGIN
MERGE INTO RPT_SCI.ORDER_FULFILLABLE TRGT
USING 
 (select * from RPT_SCI.VI_ORDER_FULFILLABLE order by CREATED_DTTM DESC) SRC 
ON  ( TRGT.TC_ORDER_ID = SRC.TC_ORDER_ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE (.............) WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (..............)
Basically I want to loop the SRC table order by create_datetime

Comment: Basically I want to loop the SRC table order by create_datetime, so that it insert or update as per the loop. I need to insert / update records like FIFO

Comment: What's the reason for this requirement? There is no way to order how Oracle merges the rows into the target table without splitting the merge statement into separate insert and update sql statements.

Comment: @Boneist - are you sure ?

Comment: Pretty sure. Feel free to peruse [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606) yourself, though! *{:-)  I'm still curious as to the reason why you need to do this, though. Ordinary heap tables in Oracle don't have any implicit ordering to how the data is stored, so I'm struggling to understand why you would care in what order the data is inserted.

Comment: Requirement is FIFO, the order which come first have get items first. I have changed the ON CLAUSE it did order by order id but when i add datetime its doesnt , dont know why..

Comment: Inserting in a specific order doesn't make sense. Rows in a relational table are ***not*** sorted. The insertion order has absolutely no relevance for the retrieval order. The ***only*** (really: the **only**) way to get a specific sort order when _retrieving_ rows is to use an `order by`.

Comment: order by on SRC ?!?.... I already tried as shown in my above example. Doesnt work

Comment: There is similar one in SQL SERVER in below link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566824/sql-server-merge-statement-and-order-by-clause

Comment: The requirement might be FIFO, but that only really makes sense if you're talking about queues or stacks. We're not, we're talking about tables, and it really doesn't make sense to do that on an ordinary heap table. What's the reasoning behind the requirement? Why do they want FIFO? What do they think that means in this context? And, for that matter, what do you mean by "first out" when talking about adding data to a table? When you select from a table, you would just add the relevant order by clause into the sql.